# How do you create a warrant in corda?

Tags: java, kotlin, blockchain, corda, smartcontracts

I need to create a warrant or a legal contract which should be transacted between nodes and change their ownership.

Comment: I am not really experienced in the tagged technics but this question seems to be a bit too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Corda Samples](http://www.corda.net/samples) page. There are plenty of samples you could use a base for your warrant or legal contract. Two good examples are the [Options](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-option) and [Obligations](https://github.com/corda/obligation-cordapp) CorDapps.